# Cucumber configuration error in IntelliJ: Please annotate a glue class with some context configuration

Tags: spring, gradle, cucumber, cucumber-java

So I recently started working on Cucumber and have been facing this issue.

This is the hierarchy of my module [image]

As you can see this is submodule in my Spring Boot application (AcceptanceTests), so there are no main methods in it.

This is my `CucumberSpringContextConfiguration` class

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
public class CucumberSpringContextConfiguration {
}
```

This is my `CucumberIntegrationTest` class

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  features = "src\test\resources\feature",       
  plugin = {"pretty", "html:target\\cucumber"}, 
  glue = "com.#####.########.cucumberspringboot.cucumberglue"
)
public class CucumberIntegrationTest {}
```

I tried running this code with a main class (src/main/java),the code compiled successfully. But since that is not my requirement I removed it and now I am getting below error -

```
SEVERE: Exception while executing pickle
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Please annotate a
glue class with some context configuration.

  For example:

     @CucumberContextConfiguration    
     @SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)    
     public class CucumberSpringConfiguration { } 

  Or: 
  
     @CucumberContextConfiguration
     @ContextConfiguration( ... )   
     public class CucumberSpringConfiguration { }   
  
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
  at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:93)
  at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:92) 
  at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:34) 
Caused by: io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: 
  Please annotate a glue class with some context configuration.
```

Please suggest how to achieve this without using main class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:92) at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:34)
> ```

This part of the stacktrace shows you are using the Cucumber CLI rather than `CucumberIntegrationTest`. So you are probably running your feature file through IDEA. Presumably you clicked the green play icon in the gutter of a feature file.

Unfortunately Intelij IDEA makes some assumptions and bad guesses. If you look at the run configuration that was created you'll see that there is a command line with `--glue` argument that probably points at `features`. You'll have to change this manually.

It is currently unnecessary to guess the `--glue` argument and I have already asked the team behind Intelij IDEA to fix this at [IDEA-243074](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243074/Do-not-suggest-glue-packages-for-Cucumber-v6.0.0) but the issue has gotten zero attention so far. You can upvote it, maybe something happens.

You can also avoid this problem by putting your feature files in a different location e.g. `src/test/resources/com/#####/########/cucumberspringboot`. Becaus this is the parent package of `cucumberglue` Ingelij IDEA is less likely to mess things up.

Also note: you are currently using JUnit 4 to run Cucumber. Spring Boot prefers using JUnit 5. You should use the [Cucumber JUnit Platform Engine](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine).  You can find a [minimal example here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton).

Comment: Passing the correct package name in `--glue`(inside build.gradle config) helped with the error, but still I cant run gradle cucumber command without a main method in my project. It throws this error -> io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Please annotate a glue class with some context configuration.

Comment: What is the Gradle Cucumber command? You may want to use JUnit 5 instead. You can find an example here https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton